# unable to filter out xscreensaver at ccsm opacity plugin?

Tags: ccsm, xscreensaver, xdotool

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/147593/157532), I managed to lower the problem concerning "Focus & Raise Behaviour" = "Very High", by using the "opacity, brightness and saturation" plugin setting "any" window to 95% opacity.

The problem is, it also matches `xscreensaver`, and this wont work here:

```
(any) & !(class=xscreensaver-demo | class=xscreensaver | class=Xscreensaver-demo | class=Xscreensaver)
```

So when it activates, I can see my desktop windows thru the xscreensaver!!! what I do now?

I tried to track xscreensaver window class using `xprop` but "the window" (is it a window?) cant be found by `xdotool` after I get the pid of xscreensaver or its child (the actual running screensaver) and try to find its window id as that cant be found...

Comment: Try *name=xscreensaver*

Comment: @totti so simple and is now fixed, thx! but I cant mark as solved unless it is put as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(any) & !(name=xscreensaver)
```